# Reading a text file multiple times in different functions and accessing these functions in one main function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a text file multiple times in different functions, and accessing the functions in one single main function.

My main function code:

```
def Get_Input_And_Create_Ndf(Opened_File):
    Node_Description(Opened_File)
    Number_Of_Inputs = int(raw_input("Please enter number of GUI Parameters: "))
    Input_Number = 0
    for Input_Number in range(Number_Of_Inputs):
        Input_Number = Input_Number+1
        GUI_Parameter = str(raw_input("Please enter input parameter " + str(Input_Number) + " :"))
        Data_Type = str(raw_input("Please select any of the following data type \n double \n float \n unsigned char  \n string \n int \n long \n bool  \n long double \n long long :"))
        Default_Value = str(raw_input("Please select the default value for the parameter (Press Enter to skip): "))
        Render_Option = str(raw_input("Please set the rendering mode (Select either cpu or gpu) :"))
        if (Input_Number == 1):
            Instructions_And_Brackets(Opened_File, "messages", "(")
        if (Input_Number == 1, Input_Number <= Number_Of_Inputs):
            pass
            Message_Description(Opened_File, GUI_Parameter, Data_Type, Default_Value)
        if (Input_Number == Number_Of_Inputs):
            Instructions_And_Brackets(Opened_File, "", ")")
        else:
            pass
    Cpp_File_Path = Get_Cpp_File()
    Opened_Cpp_File = Open_Cpp_File(Cpp_File_Path)
    Instructions_And_Brackets(Opened_File, "members", "{{")
    Found_Mem_Functions = Find_Member_Functions(Opened_File, Opened_Cpp_File)
    Instructions_And_Brackets(Opened_File, " ", "}};")
    Instructions_And_Brackets(Opened_File, "prepend ", "{{ \n")
    Prepended_Data = Find_Prepend_Data(Opened_File, Opened_Cpp_File)
    Instructions_And_Brackets(Opened_File, "", "}}; \n")
    Instructions_And_Brackets(Opened_File, "append", "{{ \n")
    Function_Definition_Data = Find_Function_Definitions(Opened_File, Opened_Cpp_File)
```

Problematic functions :

```
   Found_Mem_Functions = Find_Member_Functions(Opened_File, Opened_Cpp_File) 
   Prepended_Data = Find_Prepend_Data(Opened_File, Opened_Cpp_File)
   Function_Definition_Data = Find_Function_Definitions(Opened_File, Opened_Cpp_File)
```

All the functions work fine when I comment out other two functions and use only one function. But if I have all three functions in the main function. Only the function which I have declared first works. Here **Find_Member_Functions**. I couldn't understand what's wrong here !...

Implementation of Reset function:

```
def Reset_File(Opened_File, Opened_Cpp_File):
    Opened_File.seek(0)
    Opened_Cpp_File.seek(0)
    return
```

Comment: OMG! this hurts my eyes! please read PEP-8 and rename your variables and functions... http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the file after each call. Because the file is consumed by each function call so you set file cursor back to the start of the file.

```
Opened_File.seek(0)
```

Comment: This worked ! Except with a minor correction for me as I am reading from Opened_Cpp_File and writing it to Opened_File. I don't have to reset the Opened_File as I am writing there, reseting will in make the data loss. This worked for me `Opened_File.seek(0)`

Comment: Ah, yes, I misinterpreted and thought you were reading both files